# C# 2022 IDE - not warning about code styles or variable naming?

Tags: c#, naming, roslyn-code-analysis

New install of Visual Studio 2022 - NET 6 project.

In the past, the variables (in the pic below) would have little squiggles underneath them and when I hover the mouse over them a suggestion would pop up stating something similar to (names are not cased or capitalized correctly).  It was like the IDE had a code analyzer (maybe an extension/addon) that constantly monitored coding styles.

After installing VS 2022 I cannot figure out how to make these types of suggestions appear.  Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Edit - Additional info

I think, maybe it's rule `IDE1006` that I am trying to activate in the IDE

Also, in (Tools)(Options) I have these settings. But not a single notification about variable names that violate `IDE1006`

[image]

I can see all of these notifications too (pic below), so, I know with certainty the code is being analyzed (the analysis is just not pointing out (variable name) violations)

[image]

Comment: This is bizarre. I know it used to work in 2022, to the point that I have settings in .editorconfig to disable the naming rules on certain files (imported from C headers). I just checked again, and now -like yours- none of them are being enforced after removing the custom settings. Still not sure what is happening..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting for enabling and disabling specific style guidance selections.

[image]

You will need to navigate to Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Code Style/General

Answer (score 1):

In addition to catching flat out syntax errors, Visual Studio does have code analyzers.

This feature still works. Looking at your image, it appears there are those dotted lines under `offet_A` and `offetBecause`. It's hard to know exactly why because I don't have enough context of the few lines we're looking at.

I do know that method names starting with lower-case letter generally trigger this warning, but again, we can't see if you have that going on either.

So my answer is this feature is still active. But it only happens for naming that violates accepted naming conventions.

Comment: The dotted lines/warning on (offet_A) and (offetBecause) are (IDE0059 Unnecessary assignment of a value to offet_A) due to the assignment of string.Empty, because string.Empty is the string's default value is a string.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my `.editorconfig` file (added the lines below), and now the Style Rules, specifically (IDE1006 naming rule violation), etc are enabled/flagged in my source code

```
dotnet_naming_rule.locals_should_be_camel_case.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.locals_should_be_camel_case.symbols = locals_and_parameters
dotnet_naming_rule.locals_should_be_camel_case.style = camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.locals_and_parameters.applicable_kinds = parameter, local
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_style.capitalization = camel_case
```

[image]